# Convert a NSString to unicode

Tags: ios

I have some non-european characters like @"á".

And I'm looking for a method that can convert those character to unicode like this online tool

[UTF-8 to Unicode Converter](http://ratfactor.com/utf-8-to-unicode)

Example: á = \u00E1

And I can get "\u00E1" like a NSString.

Anyone can show me how?

Comment: An NSString *is* Unicode.

Comment: I knew that. but I want to get that code by string

Comment: In other words, you want the non-7-bit characters escaped?

Comment: Yup.Exactly! How to do that?

Comment: @GấuUni By using the second answer to this question, which is more than generous (i.e. it does 95% of it for you).

Comment: I tried it. It does exactly like I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange:
```

or

```
- (NSData *)dataUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

Using one of the following encodings `NSUTF16StringEncoding`, `NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding`, `NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding`.

But why do you want to do this, what are you truing to accomplish? `NSString` handles unicode by default. The statement "UTF-8 to Unicode Converter", what do you mean by 'Unicode'? The byte string, a `unichar`?

Example code"

```
NSString *s = @"á";
unichar uc;
[s getBytes:&uc maxLength:2 usedLength:NULL encoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, 1) remainingRange:NULL];
NSLog(@"uc: %04x", uc);

NSString *u = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\u%04x", uc];
NSLog(@"%@", u);
```

NSLog output:

> uc: 00e1
>   \u00e1

Comment: Because I want to use this character in some other language like sql or kind of. So I use this unicode string to every languages can understand. Like a standard form.

Comment: Did you visit that page? copy this character "á" and convert it. You will get a string \u00E1. And I want to do that in iOS. Is this possible?

Comment: Yeah. This is what I'm looking for. Thanks thousand times

Comment: This doesn't work for emoji or other chars which require more than 16-bit unicode.  For that, need to increase uc to 4 bytes, set the encoding to NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding AND, oddly, set the range to 2 characters.  The last requirement seems like a bug.

Comment: @user1055568 The ansswer is nrrowly aimed at the quewstion. Nor does it handle multi codepoimt characters such as flag:  (utf-16 U+1F1EF U+1F1EA) and emoji groups: ‍‍‍(utf-16 U+1F468 U+200D U+1F468 U+200D U+1F467 U+200D U+1F467) or (utf-8 F0 9F 91 A8 E2 80 8D F0 9F 91 A8 E2 80 8D F0 9F 91 A7 E2 80 8D F0 9F 91 A7). In the coment 2 character are reqiuired because ObjC unicode is UTF-16 and index by UTF-16, Swift 4 greatly improved unicode character handling.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for this kind of thing:

```
NSString* s1 = @"á";
NSString* s2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%X", [s1 characterAtIndex:0]];
NSLog(@"%@", s2);
```

Comment: Still not. Please check the link I mentioned. I want to do sth like that

Comment: The format you want is: @"\\u%04X"

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.